# PHP - SSH tunnel to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

How to make self destructing SSH tunnel to access MySQL on another server?

Currently my code looks like:

```
exec('ssh -fNg -L 4343:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remotehost.com');

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'dbuser', 'dbpass', 'dbname', '4343');
```

Problem here is that script hangs after making exec command. How should 
 i execute rest of the script, and how to close background process once the script has finished?

Comment: Try `shell_exec`  shell_exec returns all of the output stream as a string. `exec`  ***returns the last line of the output by default***

Comment: Problem here is that i don't need any output from exec/shell_exec. Idea is to spawn background process that holds SSH tunnel and "move it out of the way" for php script to execute.

Comment: try something like `exec('ssh -fNg -L 4343:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remotehost.com . &');`

Answer (score 1):

So after some research - solution is to add  `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` on the end of command.

Complete working example line is:

```
exec('ssh -fNg -L 4343:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remotehost.com > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```